# EF code first migration error (migrate.exe) - Type is not resolved for member

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, ef-code-first, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to do a database migration remotely from the app server. 
When I run the migration(via powershell and octopus deploy) I get the following error

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+UpdateRunner,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
08:21:01Info
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
08:21:01Info
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Run()
08:21:01Info
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)
08:21:01Info
ERROR: Type is not resolved for member 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade+UpdateRunner,EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

And what I'm running is something like the following

```
migrate.exe D:\test\apps\myproject.domain.dll /startupConfigurationFile='D:\test\apps\myapp.config'
```

I have already checked the path making sure there aren't any & or anything special and tried few different paths

And tried few config tweaks suggested in other posts and tried adding the following configs

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>

<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework" requirePermission="false"/>
```

Still no luck !
Any thoughts please ?

Thanks in advance